# Express/Ngnix serving the wrong html file regardless of route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx

Whatever file I try to serve, express always returns `admin.html`

If I remove `admin.html`, express throws an error on the admin route (caught by my removed error handler), but continues to serve the admin page on other routes, even when the page isn't there

I've the following file structure:

```
// /var/www/my-site:

  express-app
    |--public
    |    |--admin.html
    |    |--index.html
    |    |--index.bundle.[hash].js
    |    |--admin.bundle.[hash].js
    |    |--// more assets
    |
    |--app.js
    |--package.json
    |--package-lock.json
    |--node_modules
```

Here are my express routes:

```
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/admin', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('path:', path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'admin.html'));
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'admin.html'));
});


app.get('/index', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('path:', path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});


app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('path:', path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

I've tried using `app.use(express.static('./public'));`, `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public/index.html'))`, with and without the relative path.

Here's how the path is being resolved/logged:

/: `No output`

/index: `path: /var/www/my-site/express-app/public/index.html`

/admin: `path: /var/www/my-site/express-app/public/admin.html`

When I use live-server locally to view `index.html` it opens the correct page.
When I view `index.html` on my server it references `index.js`, so I've not accidently confused the two files afaik, and I don't think it's an issue with my webpack config.

I've switched from `pm2` to just using node and I've restarted the server in case it's a cache issue.

I mean Nginx is obviously directing traffic to express, but here's my config on the off chance:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

     index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

      server_name my-site www.my-site.io;

      location / {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
      }
```

7 hours later and I'm completely at a loss, so would appreciate any help!

Comment: So... I have good and bad news. The bad news is that the good news are also bad news and the good news is that I tried to reproduce your example and did not manage to get it to not work. Is there maybe any way your `index.html` causes some js code to redirect you to `admin.html`? Have you tried using curl or postman or something like it instead of your browser to see the entire response you get?

Comment: XD Thanks for trying it! So after saying it couldn't be my bundler because the file works correctly locally I deleted the contents of `index.html` and replaced it with a basic page, and it worked. But that kind of blows my mind. I don't really know where to start with it. I guess I'll try and replace the file with the locally built one again, and then check my webpack configs? I could've made a simple error, but I don't see how that explains `live-server` and `webpack server` displaying the correct content

Comment: I have stopped asking those questions and simply started accepting :P At least the first bug is found now. From now it's just trial and error. Good luck with squashing the rest of them!